# How to transform a string into an int equivalent in a deterministic way with gawk 5?

Tags: awk

I am facing a case where I need to transform a string to an int equivalent with `gawk5`.

This transformation must be deterministic.

My first, naive, approach is to convert each letter of the string to its equivalent position in the latin alphabet and then concat the results back into a string.

For example:

```
my_string = "AB"
A = 1
B = 2
my_int=12
```

However, this has several downsides:

- Very long strings may generate an integer that goes beyond [maximum integer size](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computer-Arithmetic.html#:%7E:text=gawk%20has%20facilities%20for%20performing,or%2064%20bits%20in%20size.).
- What to do in case of special characters, symbols, etc. ?
- This requires me to hold a table of each character position in the alphabet.

So, basically, it's a no go.

What is a good and robust method to generate an integer from a string with `gawk5` ?

PS: Some will comment that gawk may not be the tool for that, and they may be right and I am aware of that. But this is for a personnal project that should include only awk if possible ;)

Comment: You're basically looking for a base10 encoding of a string, right? Isn't there no way to guarantee that the number won't be larger than the maximum integer size anyway? And would [arbitrary-precision integers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Integers) maybe work?

Comment: can you define `'int equivalent'`? what are you going to do with the 'integer' once you have it? do you need to 'reverse' the operation at some point to come up with the original string? I'm having problems visualizing a scenario where you can convert an unlimited-length string of characters into a single integer (that doesn't blow out some 'max int' limit); and if you plan on 'reversing' the operation ... how do you know if `12` is `1` + `2` (ie, 2 characters) vs `12` (single character)?

Comment: As you do not define what a "_character_" is, it is difficult to answer (they could be multi-byte UTF characters, for instance). But if your characters are ASCII characters your could simply convert each of them in 3-digits numbers (`065`for `A`...). Would it be OK for your need?

Comment: @BenjaminW. It seems that I am looking for base10 encoding ! I'll look at your link, thanks for the source.

Comment: @markp-fuso: I have no specific requirement for "int equivalent". I am looking for a way to generate an int, in a deterministic way, from a string. It could be by dancing arround a fire or doing some crazy math, as long as I always have the same int at the end. After some research, something like the java hashcode or Benjamin's base10 encoding seems to be what I am looking for.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Correct, I did not. Lets say I am working with ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string contains only ASCII characters, no newlines, and if you use GNU awk, the following simply converts each character into its 3-digits ASCII code:

```
$ echo "abc" | awk -vFS= '
    BEGIN {for(i=0;i<128;i++) c[sprintf("%c",i)]=i}
    {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%03d",c[$i])}'
097098099
```

Of course this expands the string by a factor of 3, which can be sub-optimal. If you know that your string contains only ASCII characters in the 32-127 range you can reduce this factor to 2:

```
$ echo "abc" | awk -vFS= '
    BEGIN {for(i=32;i<128;i++) c[sprintf("%c",i)]=i-32}
    {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%02d",c[$i])}'
656667
```